# Facebook learns my typeahead searches - how to "delete"

Tags: facebook, privacy, search

I have already deleted my search history but it seems that Facebook learnt my searches. Eg. There are 4 names starting with xy: xya, xyb, xyc, xyd Once I have searched for xyc and after it I have also deleted the logs. But now every time I type xy into the search input box, Facebook shows the name of xyc instead of showing all the names starting with xy or just some names eg. xya, xyb... It specially shows that name I have already searched.

1. How can I disable this?
2. How can I remove the names?
3. If 1,2 are not possible is there any workaround?
   E.g. teach Facebook xyb instead of xyc?

I think this is against privacy.

The mentioned people are not my friends, not my followers, I am not their follower.

It is a fact that when I use Facebook from my PC I don't get the same typeahead suggestions as on mobile. The mobile ones annoy me, I would like to delete them but I am unable.

Comment: Please see my [late answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80686/97500) for a real solution and not a workaround to your issue.

Comment: Okay, I saw your rejected edit. You should post such information into the comments section. Are these names you begin to enter your friends/followers or something?

Comment: Please [request a merge of your accounts](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/contact) so you can edit your posts properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically weighted searching. If you've been searching for xyc constantly then it makes sense to have that as the first item. The only way to override this will be to search for xy then continually choose consistently an option other than xyc. Depending on how long you have been searching for xyc will determine how far down xyc gets pushed in the list.

If you believe this is a breach of privacy you should report it to Facebook.

Summary: No, there is no way to delete this.

Comment: Correct answer. About privacy: I think 1) everybody should be able to clear all the searches (s)he made 2) everybody should be able to escape the "search bubble "

Answer (score 0):

### Summary: You can delete the Facebook-Search-History

As the former answer states, this is actually a feature: weighted search.

The functions you are looking for are a little bit hidden. When focusing the search-bar, without anything in it, right underneath it the title "Recent Searches" appears and on the right side there is a little link labeled "edit".

#### Search Activity-Log

By visiting the [Search-Activity-Overview](https://www.facebook.com/me/allactivity?privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=search) you have two possible solutions:

1. **Delete all your search-entries** by pressing "Clear Searches" in the upper right corner and confirming the question "Are you sure?".
2. **Delete individual entries** you don't want to see anymore as suggestions by first finding the entry you wish to proscribe and then pressing on the Stop-Sign ('Hidden from Timeline') and choosing Delete - again you have to confirm that.